# Error with win32com.dll in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, win32com

I am getting an error in eclipse with regards to my win32com.dll file. From the error it would appear I am trying to use a 32-bit .dll instead of a 64-bit, but unfortunately I haven't been able to find a 64-bit win32com.dll file anywhere and I'm at a loss at how to proceed. I literally downloaded Eclipse tonight and this is my first time writing in Java, so please be gentle.

Thanks!

> Error loading win32com: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\bin\win32com.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD
>   64-bit platform

**EDIT:** I think Java discontinued support of the Java Communications API, but I'm not really sure what else to do to fix this. Can anyone point to a good serial port Java example? I haven't been able to find one anywhere...

Comment: whats your eclipse's version?

Comment: Version: Juno Service Release 2  
Build id: 20130225-0426.  I can't find the normal version number anywhere. Is this good enough?

Comment: I've actually got to head out and probably won't check this until tomorrow. Thanks for any suggestions you can throw my way :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I gave up on this and switched to [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). I think quite a few people have done this as all my research pointed to this instead of figuring out what I wanted to originally.

In a nutshell you need to do is to download the correct files from [here](http://rxtx.qbang.org/eclipse/downloads/).

Install the files in the following directories:

`rxtxParallel.dll` & `rxtxSerial.dll` --> `Program Files/Java/jre6/bin`

`RXTXComm.dll` --> `Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext`

Note that this is only for 64-bit environments. Hope this helps for anyone in my position in the future!

Answer (score 1):

I got around the same by installing 32-bit JDK instead of 64-bit one in my Windows 7 64-bit.
Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall JDK 32bit If you are using 64bit version

Comment: win32com.dll isn't part of the JDK. It's part of the [Java Communications API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) but I can't figure out where to download three important files for port support (`win32com.dll`, `javax.javax.comm.properties` and `comm.jar`).

Comment: I should note that I can't find the *64-bit* version of these three files.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the files you need at this address:
http://llk.media.mit.edu/projects/picdev/software/javaxcomm.zip

Make sure to add the jar as a library to your project.

This example seems elaborate enough using this API:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/ReadfromaSerialportnotifyingwhendataarrives.htm

Comment: Thanks @Byron, but unfortunately that is the same set of files I am currently using (i.e. the win32com.dll file is 32-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Install 32 bit **jdk** and change eclipse **run configurations** in jre tab select Alternate JRE then add 32 bit jdk's bin path