# win32com.dll in Eclipse incompatible with 64 bit version. RXTX?

Tags: eclipse, 64-bit, 32-bit, win32com, rxtx

I have a 64 Windows 7 computer, and I need to run win32com in order to create a connection between my computer and a microcontroller. However, I ran into the same problem as seen here:
[Error with win32com.dll in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378634/error-with-win32com-dll-in-eclipse/16864255#16864255)

My post on the thread above was deleted, so I'm asking the question here.

I tried downloading RXTX as tmwoods said, but I'm still having some issues. I think I misunderstand how to go installing RXTX.

I downloaded and placed the files tmwoods mentionned into my program file / java / lib (etc...) appropriately, but my Java program still needs to be referenced to the win32com.dll file, or else it won't compile. And that win32com.dll file is still in 32 bits, so Java still can't process it. (Another question I've been wondering: I also have a program File (x86) file in my Windows folder, and I noticed some RXTX downloads on the web offer a x86 version. Should I download that then?)

How can I get around this issue? Could someone please explain in more detail how to solve this problem? Thanks a bunch!

Samonac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found the solution: I used jSSC instead of RXTX, and it worked fine.

Just google java-simple-serial-connector - jSSC - java serial port communication.

Hope this will come in handy if anyone in the future has the same problem I did.